# Why Flash Media Server does not call application.onDisconnect handler?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-media-server

I've run into strange problem in my Flex/Flashcom application. If client application unexpectedly disconnects from server latter does not call application.onDisconnect handler function. In witch direction should I look? Thank you.

**Update** I'm not using server components, but I do host this thing on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [Artem Tikhomirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313/artem-tikhomirov) (the author of the question) in his [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359727#509843), my answer is not helpful (I keep there below as wiki, for archive).

The real answer has been given by [Ric Tokyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42019/ric-tokyo) regarding a [bug on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359727#486550), and is documented in [this thread](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/webforums/forum/messageview.cfm?forumid=15&catid=578&threadid=1401786&enterthread=y).

The only reason my answer is "chosen" is because Artem did not choose any other answer (or an answer of his own) before the 7 day limits, giving me (the first and most upvoted answer) half of the bounty points (75 over 150) *automatically* as explained in [this SO blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/).

---

First lead:

If the client is a component-base application, it needs to [handle connection events properly][9].

> When you develop applications, be aware that using components introduces explicit `onConnectAccept` and `onConnectReject` events.

> You need to include code to handle these events.
> When you use components, you must modify the `application.onConnect` statement in your server-side code to include the `application.onConnectAccept` and `application.onConnectReject` event handlers.
> The last line (in order of execution) of your `onConnect` handler should be either `application.acceptConnection()` or `application.rejectConnection()`.

> If your application requires additional code following the explicit `acceptConnection()` or `rejectConnection()` methods, such as a message indicating that the user has been granted or denied permission to the application, you should place that code in the `application.onConnectAccept` or `application.onConnectReject` statements.

> TIP: If you're not using media components, you cannot use `application.onConnectAccept` and `application.onConnectReject`.

---

Then, you may want to check any error message in the Flash output panel, like:

```
Error #2044: NetStatusEvent non pris en charge : level=error, code=NetStream.Play.Failed
    at MethodInfo-1()
Error #2044: NetStatusEvent non pris en charge : level=error, code=NetStream.Record.NoAccess
    at MethodInfo-1()
```

That would indicate a server exception non-taken into account by the client, forcing an unexpected exit.

If the client read a stream from the server, it must make sure:

- the NetConnection has succeeded
- the NetStreams (in and out) listen to NET_STATUS

A good code would like this:

```
var status:Function = function( e:NetStatusEvent ):void
{
    trace( "status : " + e.info.code ) ;
    if ( e.info.code == "NetConnection.Connect.Success" )
    {
        streamOut = new NetStream( nc ) ;
        streamOut.addEventListener( NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS , status ) ;
 
        streamIn  = new NetStream( nc ) ;
        streamIn.addEventListener( NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS , status ) ;
 
        streamOut.attachCamera( cam ) ;
        video.attachNetStream( streamIn ) ;
 
        streamOut.publish( "private" ) ;
        streamIn.play( "private" ) ;       
    }
}
```

Since the new versions of FlashPlayer do propagate those kind of exception, they must be monitored and then catch in the client application

Comment: OK. Thank you. I know how to handle connection events on the client. So what? How does it'll help me to overcome my server-side problem? A ton of random text isn't a good answer yet.

Comment: @Artem: I agree and left a comment on your answer explaining my position on this. I have updated my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Oh, I apologize - I was quite a jerk. Thank you for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 14):

If so, it's documented and [here](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/webforums/forum/messageview.cfm?forumid=15&catid=578&threadid=1401786&enterthread=y) an interesting forum to follow..basically on Linux it may work a bit crazy like :)

Comment: Hi Ric, according to the author of this question, your answer seems to be the correct one. Could you then please vote on http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/115548-bug-bounty-points-incorrectly-attributed-to-my-answer ?

Comment: Hi Ric, do you have a uservoice profil or uservoice points still left ? Because voting http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/115548-bug-bounty-points-incorrectly-attributed-to-my-answer would be a good idea ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I voted :) (first time I ever used this feature) thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Hi Ric, since my uservoice entry has been declined (see my updated answer above), here is a +1 for your good answer. 14 other +1 will follow, one per day, in order to not mess up with your daily rep cap of 200.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that a client is disconnected before the (Flash Media-) server 'knows' about this. So no 'onDisconnect' function gets invoked (it *never* gets called by the client) until very, very late.

If you want to detect (and act upon) "lingering" disconnects early, use the client.getStats() method.

I have this server-side actionscript example:

```
// add method to standard class
Client.prototype.isAlive = function() {
        var stats = this.getStats();
        var timeout_value = 3 * 1000;  // in ms.
        //trace('Measured timeout: ' + stats['ping_rtt']);
        if (stats)
                return (stats['ping_rtt'] < timeout_value);
}

// use this in an interval which traverses the application.clients list
if (! client.isAlive())
    application.disconnect(client);
```

You can trigger and test this 'missing onDisconnect' behavior by removing the network cable from the connected Flash client.