# Getting super class with JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

The following snippet is retrieving a Player object instance from the database. How can I make it retrieve only the User instance and then use another query to retrieve a Player instance?

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE email = :email", User.class);
User u = (User) q.setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult();
```

Inherance type is Joined.

Thank you,

Hibernate 4.3.5.Final

EDIT:
I could find [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186572/retrieve-only-the-superclass-from-a-class-hierarchy) that matches this and already flagged my question as duplicate. Thank you!

Comment: How is it returning a Player on this query?

Comment: Player inherits from the User class and the specific instance I'm testing (via the email variable), is a Player. The problem with this is that with that code I wasnt expecting a Player instance and that is what I want to understand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the superclass from a class hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186572/retrieve-only-the-superclass-from-a-class-hierarchy)