# Equivalent functionality to Google Charts API from python ? (Venn Diagrams also needed!)

Tags: python, charts

is there any library (for C or python) that I can use to get roughly the same functionality as I can get from Google Charts ?

I specifically need the pie diagrams (standard), multi-dataset-pie-diagrams (not-so-standard), and venn diagrams (rare)...

Answer (score 1):

http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/ is a Python wrapper for the Google Charts API. Also see [Pretty graphs and charts in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652/pretty-graphs-and-charts-in-python)