# Create interactive cartesian grid in django

Tags: django, django-models, cartesian, blackboard

I have a question regarding a platform I'm developing called [e-cidadania](http://gitorious.org/e-cidadania) (GPL). One of the applications will be something like a blackboard where you can put messages. I've been requested to do it like a cartesian grid (p.e. x = good/bad, y = expensive/cheap). My question is, does anybody know about an application like that for django? Or in case that there isn't, how can I do it? I have no idea where to start.

I'll explain a use case, if someone didn't understand: You are in a classroom, the teacher draws on the blackboard the axis and tells the students to write a note. After that every student will put his note according to the axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I completely understand your question, but if I'm correct you want the user to input text (name of restaurant or something like that) and instead of showing 2 sliders or dropdown boxes for rating and price, you want to show a cartesian chart where the user can click somewhere, thus entering the 2 values with one click.

This has nothing to do with Django or Python, this is pure client side. Think javascript. One way is to show an image with the cartesian grid, set an onclick handler and see where in the image the click was made. Showing the selected point could be done simply by setting a colored div with an absolute position (relative on the position of the image).

I don't know any plug-and-play solutions, but building this shouldn't be too hard.

On a separate note: I doubt this will actually be more userfriendly for the user then simply using two sliders.

Update:
Or if you want to show a big cartesian chart where the user actually has to input the text on the correct position, this can be done with the same idea: create the text-input, but hide it (display:none). Then when the user clicks somewhere on the chart, move the text-input to the correct position and show it.

Comment: It's more like your update. I've posted a basic image reflecting the UI. So you think all the work should be done directly on javascript?

Comment: I see you've added an image explaining the interface. I see that the input for entering a new message is under the chart, not inside it. Now I am confused :)

Comment: For the output of the messages on a cartesian chart you could probably use a python api, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652/pretty-graphs-and-charts-in-python.

Comment: The problem is that this is not a chart or graph, is a blackboard, like if in your class everyone writes a note and puts it on the blackboard according to the axis. I think I don't explain very well :/

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little far fetched, but instead of doing this with django alone, why dont u do this client side using javascript?

Hear me out here.

The highcharts graphing plugin has an option that allows u to add points on a (cartesian) graph. Check [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=dynamic-click-to-add&theme=default). The plugin also allows you to display custom messages when hovering on points, so you could use that to display the actual message, and you could handle the actual saving of the new message by submitting the newly added message via Ajax.