# Compoud charts with python

Tags: python, charts

I want to generate compound charts (e.g: Bar+line) from my database using python.

How can i do this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty graphs and charts in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652/pretty-graphs-and-charts-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look up [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

This is extremely simple to do using matplotlib using the `plot` and `bar` methods:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar

The matplotlib gallery is usually a good place to start for examples of working code:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy to do with pygooglechart -

You can basically follow the bar chart examples that ship with the software and then use the add_data_line method to make the lines on top of the bar chart

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering to a web browser, you might also consider jQuery and [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) using [python-flot-utils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-flot-utils/0.2.1).  If you want static images, the other two answers are correct.  [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is excellent.