# Interactive (annotated) charts in python

Tags: python

What are the best libaries for creating interactive (zoom, pan, create online annotations) charts in python?

I've checked [Pretty graphs and charts in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652/pretty-graphs-and-charts-in-python)
but this does not address zoom, pan, and annotation capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "annotation" in this context, but `matplotlib` graphs are well-suited for interactive work, and include very good zooming and panning capabilities built-in.

Comment: At first I thought the OP was referring to regular ol' [plot annotation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate), but now I'm wondering what the 'online' part means.  Anyway I'd second matplotlib, it's a great charting library.