# Graph using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing analysis of stock market data using python. I am using matplotlib to plot charts. I want to know whether there is any other library to draw charts in python. I want to draw more attractive and designer charts so that the end user will find it very attractive.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652/pretty-graphs-and-charts-in-python

Comment: I have searched the net but could not find any attractive charting library so asked this question. I am sorry if this was a very silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used charts and plots in Python before, but [Cairoplot](http://cairoplot.sourceforge.net) looks really user friendly.

These [Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=cairoplot&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=i5nrUJypE4nO9ASvs4DoBQ&biw=1280&bih=702&sei=jJnrUNrHHY369gSGh4DoCA) make it look very clean and smooth looking, so I guess you might want to try it out.