# Fancy plotting tools/libraries in python

Tags: python, graphics, charts, plot

I wanted to know if there are any other recent plotting libraries in python other than matplotlib which good visual aesthetics to publish in webpages.

I know [pyplot](https://plot.ly/) is good at this but, I want to use an offline library not an api.
This question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652/pretty-graphs-and-charts-in-python), but it was asked long back in 2008, just wanted to ask if there are any recent ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but this should help

1.https://github.com/yhat/ggplot
2.https://github.com/Kozea/pygal